Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.3.3:compile/org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException
Our prod runtime environment is now using Apache Spark 3.4
my Dev environment

Intellij
Installed Maven 3.9.9
Java 23.0.1
POM Spark ver 3.4.0
POM Scala ver 2.12.15
POM scala-maven-plugin 4.9.2
POM maven-compiler-plugin 3.13.0


Target 1.8




Source 1.8



Apache Maven 3.9.9 (8e8579a9e76f7d015ee5ec7bfcdc97d260186937)
Maven home: C:\MAVEN\apache-maven-3.9.9
Java version: 23.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-23
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
Because our prod environment is at 3.4, I'm under the impression that I need to specificy the same version locally.
This all started when I started getting a ClassNotFound error for ArraryOps$ class at runtime. Reading that this error was due to the Spark versioning, I updated my pom versions.
Now it fails at compile time, bailing out almost immediatally.
When I hit compile it bails out almost immediatally
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.842 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-10-30T15:50:55-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.9.2:compile (default) on project WUfBDSReporting: scala compilation failed -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.9.2:compile (default) on project WUfBDSReporting: scala compilation failed
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:333)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)

top level error : Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.9.2:compile
mention in logging: Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: scala compilation failed
Looking at posts,
Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile (scala-compile)
and
https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin/issues/224
they updated their scala-maven-plugin to 3.3.3.  I've tried 3.3.3, as well as 4.9.2 as well as a variety of others.
Scala version selected based off of
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Spark-Scala-Version-Compatibility-Matrix/ta-p/383713
However I still recieve the same issue.
more parts of the same error
[INFO]
[INFO]   last tree to typer: EmptyTree
[INFO]        tree position: unknown
[INFO]             tree tpe: notype
[INFO]               symbol: null
[INFO]            call site: <none> in <none
[INFO]
[INFO] == Source file context for tree position ==
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Reporting.abort(Reporting.scala:69)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Reporting.abort$(Reporting.scala:65)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.abort(SymbolTable.scala:28)
[ERROR]         at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$ConstantPool.errorBadIndex(ClassfileParser.scala:407)
[ERROR]         at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$ConstantPool.getExternalName(ClassfileParser.scala:262)

knowing very little about this, I'm a bit lost

From Overview - Apache Spark 3.4

Spark runs on Java 8/11/17, Scala 2.12/2.13, Python 3.7+, and R 3.5+. Python 3.7 support is deprecated as of Spark 3.4.0. Java 8 prior to version 8u362 support is deprecated as of Spark 3.4.0. When using the Scala API, it is necessary for applications to use the same version of Scala that Spark was compiled for. For example, when using Scala 2.13, use Spark compiled for 2.13, and compile code/applications for Scala 2.13 as well.

From Scala - JDK Compatibility




JDK
2.12




23
2.12.20





From the Spark Scala Version Compatibility Matrix you shared




Spark Version
Cloudera Supported Binary Version(s)
Scala 2.12




3.4.2
2.12
2.12.17


3.4.1
2.12
2.12.17


3.4.0
2.12
2.12.17





Sounds like you want to setup a local env to do some test in your machine, but the job will be executed in cloudera.
It doesn't look like JDK 23 is an option yet. I think you would need to downgrade JDK to a lower version. Not sure why you need target and source as 1.8, maybe you could do the upgrade to jdk 11.
My guess is that the problem is not exactly the plugin. I would focus on check which are the right versions between jdk, scala and apache spark you need to use

I don't think that combination of Apache Spark, JDK and Scala versions will work.

Apache Spark 3.4 doesn't support jdk 23.
jdk 23 support scala 2.12.20 (not 2.12.15)
why you are using target and source 1.8 for jdk 23?


from what the 1st menion says, "Spark runs on Java 8/11/17, Scala 2.12/2.13", my options here are limited.  That is if I'm on spark 3.4, my only java options are 8/11/17 (no other versions will work), and my only options for Scala are 2.12 and 2.13 (no other options will work..
My source/target are 1.8 because I was reading that 1.8 translates to jdk 8. https://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html

Okay, Thank you Gaston... with your pointers it gave me a direction to investigate and I believe I have it resolved now... Specifically the jdk 23 area.   Adding details in an answer ost

As @gaston (I don't know how to @mention people here) pointed out and as I half suspected there were versioning issues as with all the other instances we see of this issues on SO.  what I did to resolve it was

Spark 3.4 works with Java 8/11/17.  I in my daze followed some odd documentation, but in the end for this item I - Added Java 17 from Settings -> Project Settings -> Project -> SDK -> azul-17.       Then udpated my source/target for the maven plugin to 17's.  Then from the Maven Project view Reloaded the project

So now the project will compile with all the latest available for Spark 3.4
However that brings me to my next blocker..... (barf)
2024-10-30 17:14:14,980 ERROR ApplicationMaster [Driver]: User class threw exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/ArrayOps$
I'll be investigating this now, and perhaps another SO post..

Not possible to do mentions in answers, only in comments. Answers should be to solve the problem, not to detail a new issue or ask new question. Instead of that, you should mark my answer as the solution and start new question or edit this question adding more context
